# Upgrade classic app to lightining

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, salesforce-classic, upgrade

I just upgrade my classic app to lightining and now my question is how do I deploy to sandbox(qa) using changeset?

my sandbox(qa) already has the classic app so I'm not really sure what is the best way to approach?

Should I upgrade the app in sandbox(qa) ? and staging and then production or deploy using the changeset?

appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upgrade your classic App to the Lightning App, a new App is created generally with a suffix _Lighnting!

You can use the changesets to move this. It is metadata of type [CustomApplication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customapplication.htm)

> Note rest of the metadata will be the same as your classic app so all you need is this app in the changeset unless you have added new metadata like say a new tab.

Comment: that's correct it creates `_lightining` but if I add the app to my changeset it's not creating all the depend metadata like pagelayouts, listviews, tab etc.... do I need to add each individually ?

Comment: Will, it is not same as the classic apps? Note rest of the metadata will be the same so all you need is this app in the changeset unless you have added new metadata like say a new tab. Hope that helps

Comment: awesome, that's all I wanted to verify if I needed to add other metadata or just the app is enough but looks like i just need to add the app in the changeset and deploy right? so let me give it a try.

Comment: yes, you can just deploy and that should be it! Of course, do not forget about profiles if you have provided access etc

Comment: one last question, should I delete the classic app or keep it and delete later once I confirm everything is working as expected?

Comment: I would just hide it at this point, once everything is stable then you can get rid of it